# Why do Jedi practice lightsaber dueling, and not blaster fire deflection techniques?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, lightsaber

I recall reading somewhere that many of the Jedi practice lightsaber techniques that are specifically for dueling with other lightsabers. It went on to say **the fact that they utilized fencing techniques was the reason why so many died on Geonosis in the first battle of the Clone war.** The heroes we follow used fighting techniques that were also good against blaster fire, which is why they survived.

Now, fighting directly against the Sith in a lightsaber duel seems historically to be a fairly rare occurrence (rule of 2, etc.) and such situations comprise a very small part of a Jedi's duties leading up to the Clone Wars. Usually, they are up against enemies with blasters, darts, thermal detonators, etc.

**Why don't the Jedi focus their training on fighting against blaster fire instead of dueling?**

If anyone is an expert on lightsaber techniques and their names, feel free to edit liberally.

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate this is. Even the younglings we see training with lightsabers are working with remote droids that appear to be similar to the one Luke used for training against blaster fire.

Comment: Jedi seem to be not so bad at deflecting singular blaster shots, but they were _vastly_ outnumbered on Geonosis, and thus seemed to be poor at it.

Comment: @phantom42 - Perhaps that early experience stigmatizes this sort of practice as kids' stuff.

Comment: I thought my answer to this one was reasonably solid, given the book quote. Is there anything else you'd want me to address before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum your answer is great, but I think it only addresses part of the question. Most of a jedi's duties as a peacekeeper are spent dealing with blasters, etc. Wouldn't they find other techniques to be more practical? I was focusing my question more on that aspect and less on fighting sith.

Comment: @TBear - Better now? Most Jedi can deflect bolts with relative ease, but only a few Masters are capable of sending them back where they came from. Faced with dozens of well-armed enemies, the average Jedi would be toast.

Comment: Just a comment as I won't present references. tldr; they didn't train for battle. points: 1) they see duelling as useful exercise such as people nowadays train Aikido and similar although the skills would not directly be useful in a modern war.  2) Most Jedis didn't fight - the have large sections doing research, training, agriculture and so on.  3) also the ones policing didn't fight much - most police doesn't have daily firefight in our world as well - leave alone war. 4) the war against Sith is a spiritual one, fought by resisting temptation and leading a life of sacrifice.

Comment: On their peacekeeper role, jedi were more of ambassadors and diplomats than anything else. Yes they had sabers and were more than capable in combat, but their role wasn't to block shots between parties. They were there to find compromises and peacefully resolve conflicts. On top of that, they aren't being sent out for every little fight between 2 people. They are sent out to resolve conflicts between two groups of people, generally. I would not expect them to deal with any weapons in most of their peacekeeper duties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yoda's internal monologue in the Revenge of the Sith novelisation is especially telling. In short, as leader of the Jedi (for the best part of a thousand years) he's been assiduously training young Jedi to **re-fight the last war**. That means an over-emphasis on lightsaber fighting and a dramatic under-reliance on things that might have actually helped them; winning the hearts and minds of the populace and engaging in espionage that might help to root out any dark side users of the Force.

> *He’d never had it. He had lost before he started.*
>
> *He had lost before he was born.*
>
> *The Sith had changed. The Sith had grown, had adapted, had invested a
> thousand years’ intensive study into every aspect of not only the
> Force but Jedi lore itself, in preparation for exactly this day. The
> Sith had remade themselves.*
>
> *They had become new. While the Jedi- **The Jedi had spent that same
> millennium training to refight the last war.***
>
> *The new Sith could not be destroyed with a lightsaber; they could not
> be burned away by any torch of the Force. The brighter his light, the
> darker their shadow. How could one win a war against the dark, when
> war itself had become the dark’s own weapon?*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith - Official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

---

To put it another way, Yoda was expecting the Sith (or whoever) to turn up like this

[image]

rather than like this

[image]

And encouraged training that would suit this kind of fight.

---

As to the question of blaster *deflection*, this is something that the Jedi do deal with in their early training. We see younglings practicing with the same sort of [remote](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Remote) that Obi-Wan had Luke swinging at.

Various articles about lightsaber training (including the excellent [Fightsaber](http://www.dmeb2.com/darthmaulsection/swinsider62.html)) address the fact that while many Jedi are happy to deflect blaster bolts (using a modified form III), relatively few were willing to take this to the next level with Form V (deflecting bolts back on those who had fired) for ethical reasons. A fully trained Jedi might still be ill-equipped to deal with the sort of threat that dozens of well-trained and blaster-equipped soldiers would pose.

[image]

Comment: Yep, the Jedi from that _SW:TOR_ trailer got thrashed rather quick. Always one step behind :(

Comment: "Yoda was expecting" - at least in that monologue, Yoda was exactly *not* expecting that, but most of the Jedi order acted as *they* were expecting what you describe.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - He wasn't specifically expecting the Sith, but he was certainly anticipating that dark side users (of some description) would turn up mob-handed. If the Sith had been dumb enough to confront the Jedi directly, they'd have been massacred.

Comment: @Valorum Darth Maul would have supported that distorted way of thinking. He was certainly your run-of-the-mill lightsaber-wielding Sith.